# Can we have different Routes for different environments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API Controller. I would like to have different URL structures for different environments, how can I do that?  Can we definte routes in Web.Config?

For instance in dev I want host/dev/api/controllername and for Production I want host/api/controllername

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add one more key in your web.config to specify the environment.
For example:

```
<add key="Environment" value="Development" />
```

Then, in your Application_Start, you read value of this configuration from web.config and register routing accordingly.

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
            var environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"].ToString();

            if (environment.Equals("Development"))
            {
                  routes.MapPageRoute("", "dev/{action}/{categoryName}","~/categoriespage.aspx");
            }

    }
```

For your references: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx